# Unable to decode Base64 data that contains HTML content in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, decode, nsdata

I'm having one URL(https://dces-tools-log.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sqe/demo/INT/3/c1.0) that returns `base64` `data` contains `HTML` content.

I'm decoding response string in the following way but It's giving `null`.

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:responseString options:0];

NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Your text is too long, so i can't test. But you can check your data is null or not to check which line cause problem

Comment: @QuocNguyen : Thanks for your quick response. I'm able get data but decodedString is coming as null

Comment: Change your `NSUTF8StringEncoding`  to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` you will get the result (I tested it)

Comment: @QuocNguyen : Thank  you very much. It's working fine.